# facing comparision issue in javascript

Tags: javascript

this is what is my java script function :

```
function issueOrReturn() {
    var functiontype = document.getElementById("functiontype").value;
    alert("functiontype : "+functiontype);
    if (functiontype=="issueTempcard") {
        alert("1111111111111111111111111");
        var empid = document.getElementById("empid").value;
        var tempcardnumber = document.getElementById("tempcardnumber").value;
        var dateofissue = document.getElementById("dateofissue").value;
        if(empid.length==0) {
            alert("Please enter Employee ID ");
            return false;
        }
        if(tempcardnumber.length==0) {
            alert("Please enter Card Number ");
            return false;
        }
        if(dateofissue.length==0) {
            alert("Please enter Date of issue ");
            return false;
        }
        if(empid.length > 0 && tempcardnumber.length > 0 && dateofissue.length > 0) {
            document.forms["frmTempcard"].submit();
        } else {
            alert("Please enter Employee ID and and Card Number and Date of issue ");
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (functiontype == "returnTempCard") {
        alert("222222222222222222222222222222");
        var empid = document.getElementById("empid").value;
        var dateofreturn = document.getElementById("dateofreturn").value;

        if (empid.length == 0) {
            alert("Please enter Employee ID ");
            return false;
        }
        if (dateofreturn.length == 0) {
            alert("Please enter Date of return ");
            return false;
        }
        if (empid.length > 0 && dateofreturn.length > 0) {
            document.forms["frmTempcard"].submit(); 
        } else {
            alert("Please enter Employee ID and Date of return ");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

here the functiontype is : `issueTempcard` the alert is printed but it is not getting in the if loop of `issueTempcard` hence the form is not submitted,

also please advise me whether the following way is correct to submit the form :

```
if (empid.length > 0 && tempcardnumber.length > 0 && dateofissue.length > 0) {
    document.forms["frmTempcard"].submit(); 
} else {
    alert("Please enter Employee ID and and Card Number and Date of issue ");
}
```

kindly provide me some help so that i can do it.

Regards,

Comment: That's a lot of code. Can you provide a working [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: thanks, but don't know the reason for downvoting?

Comment: Wasn't me that downvoted, I always try to explain why if I do.

Comment: Yeah it's not *that* much code. It's not particularly well formatted, but doesn't seem worth a down-vote.

Comment: I don't see any issues with this, try tracing the code with Firebug to see what value `functiontype` actually contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your function definitions miss their closing `}` character.
Because of this, they are not executed (because the javascript interpreter fails to read your entire function)

This [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qYttv/) shows your code up and running without a hitch.
All i did is add the `}`

To help you debug your JS code, try using [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/firebug/), which can show you where you went wrong ;)

Your way of submitting forms looks fine to me, but is also missing the trailing `}`

Comment: Thanks for the post, but the code works for the `(functiontype == "returnTempCard")` and it is not working for `(functiontype == "issueTempCard")` that's why i am confused.

Comment: it seems to be working on both accounts in the jsFiddle.
Are you sure you are putting the right strings into the `document.getElementById("functiontype").value` ?

Comment: yes i tried testing in jsFiddle but not in application Timothy,confused, tried to find it out with firebug, but could not could you help?

Comment: If you open your original code (not the jsfiddle) with firefox, and open firebug (F12 is the default key binding), open the scripts tab and find your script.
Then put a `breakpoint` on the line where you do `document.getElementById("functiontype").value`.
then run your code.
it will hit the breakpoint, and you can then see what value is in `document.getElementById("functiontype").value` by hovering over it with your mouse.
Is that value the same as the strings you are comparing later on?

Comment: Thanks Timothy, acutally it was a spelling mistake that the value is `issueTempCard` but i compare with `issueTempcard` `c` and `C` is the problem.

Comment: i figured so. ;) glad you got it sorted.